# ROI (Region of Interest) is showing two lines inside same bounding box in Image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to detect each line perfectly with ROI boxes on Hindi image, But problem is, the two line having Big bold text are coming inside same ROI. You can see in the image below -

[image]

Original Image -[image]

Each line must be detected as seperate line accurately. Here is the sources code -

```
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
  image = cv2.imread('datasets/0010_jpg.rf.e7741188a2afa6db3dee4324e8486a34.jpg')

  # Display the image
  # cv2_imshow(image)

  # Convert image to grayscale
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  # cv2_imshow(gray)

  # Convert grayscale image to binary
  ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
  # cv2_imshow(thresh)

   # Apply Canny edge detection
  edges = cv2.Canny(thresh, 50, 150)  # Adjust the threshold values as needed
  # cv2_imshow(edges)

  # Dilation
  kernel = np.ones((5, 200), np.uint8)
  img_dilation = cv2.dilate(edges, kernel, iterations=1)
  # cv2_imshow(img_dilation)

  # Find contours
  contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_dilation.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

  # Sort contours based on their bounding box coordinates
  bounding_boxes = [cv2.boundingRect(ctr) for ctr in contours]
  sorted_contours = [ctr for _, ctr in sorted(zip(bounding_boxes, contours), key=lambda pair: pair[0][1])]

  # Loop over sorted contours
  for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_contours):
      # Get bounding box
      x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)

      # Getting ROI
      roi = image[y:y+h-5, x:x+w]
      roi_row = roi.shape[0]
      roi_col = roi.shape[1]

      # Show ROI
      if(roi_row>3000 or roi_row<=20 or roi_row<=10 or roi_col<=110):
          continue
      print(i)
      print(roi_row,roi_col)
      cv2_imshow(roi)
      cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (90, 0, 255), 2)

  cv2_imshow(image)
```

Comment: use `RETR_ALL` instead of `RETR_EXTERNAL` and filter wrt area and `h`

Comment: otherwise the innermost components (single bold lines) will not be detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem of accurately capturing two lines of text within the same bounding rectangle (ROI) by implementing the following steps:

**1. Height Threshold for Two Lines Detection:** I observed that when the height (h) of the bounding rectangle exceeded 60 pixels, there was a high likelihood of it containing two lines of text. To leverage this observation, I set a height threshold of 60 pixels.

**2. Splitting ROIs Vertically:** Upon detecting a bounding rectangle with a height greater than the threshold, I split the ROI vertically into two separate regions. This was achieved by dividing the ROI into two halves, representing each line of text.

```
if h > 60:
    # Split ROI into two separate ROIs vertically
    roi1 = roi[:h//2, :]
    roi2 = roi[h//2:, :]

    # Update rectangle for the first ROI
    cv2.rectangle(self.image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h//2), (90, 0, 255), 2)

     # Update rectangle for the second ROI
    cv2.rectangle(self.image, (x, y + h//2), (x + w, y + h), (90, 0, 255), 2)

    k += 2
  else:
    # Update rectangle for the ROI
    cv2.rectangle(self.image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (90, 0, 255), 2)

    k += 1
```